# Lowest bandwidth consumption in widows application while accessing database and other web services

Tags: c#, mysql, web-services

I have developed one desktop application which communicates with database for DML queries and call some other web services for showing third party data in my application.

It developed successfully and running fine.
But my new task to keep working that application on lowest internet speed around 512 Kb to 1 Mbps.
My application working on above 2 Mbps perfectly.
it gets slowed when internet speed is 512 kb or 1 Mbps.

I really appreciate if anyone take out me from this.

Comment: Since it is a desktop application, you can cache some data if they are static or atleast static for some time. Create separate threads to execute the DB queries, service calls, so your UI thread will not be blocked. You can also use data compression for your services.

Comment: Sounds like your data transfer across the wire is your problem. Check the size of the produced XML that gets sent on request and response. In cases like this it would be wise to use a top down approach on the service and design the request and response so you can move common elements out into separate structure to reduce on the bloat.